# Export all The extended ASCII codes (character code 128-255) in XML file from oracle store procedure

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing, plsqldeveloper

I have created a Store Procedure to generate an xml file of Table Data,
but in my database some table have `"extended ASCII codes (character code 128-255)"`.

When I generate xml file then it shows error  `"ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed."`

So I replaced these Char to space but **I need all ASCII codes (character code 128-255) in XML files.**

Please help

My Store Procedure is below:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE Export_project6
(
   V_TABLE_NAME1 IN varchar2,
   v_FLAG OUT NUMBER
  )
AS
BEGIN
         ----- Export  table data
     DECLARE
        v_file  UTL_FILE.file_type;
        qryCtx DBMS_XMLGEN.ctxHandle;
        result CLOB;
        v_FILENAME varchar2(50);
        V_TABLE_NAME varchar2(50);
        xt_data xmltype;
        v_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
        rc_data sys_refcursor;



      BEGIN
         V_TABLE_NAME := UPPER(V_TABLE_NAME1) ;      
         v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML',V_TABLE_NAME||'.xml', 'W');
            OPEN rc_data FOR
                 'select * FROM '||V_TABLE_NAME||' ORDER BY 1' ;
                  v_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext (rc_data);
                  DBMS_XMLGEN.USEITEMTAGSFORCOLL (v_ctx);
                  DBMS_XMLGEN.SETNULLHANDLING(v_ctx, 1);
                  DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowsettag(v_ctx,'root');
                  DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowtag(v_ctx,V_TABLE_NAME );
          result:=  DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(v_ctx);
          result := REPLACE( result, '<?xml version="1.0"?>','<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone ="yes"?>');
          -- DBMS_XMLGEN.RESTARTQUERY (v_ctx);  
          -- xt_data := dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType (v_ctx);

          dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file( result, 'MYXML', ''||V_TABLE_NAME||'.xml',1);
          dbms_xmlgen.closeContext (v_ctx);
          v_FLAG := 1;

      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
          DBMS_XMLGEN.closeContext (v_ctx);
          v_FLAG := 0;
      END ;
```

Please Advices and help here

```
END Export_project6;
```

Comment: What are your database and national character sets? And which line throws the error? Why are you explicitly setting the output file type to ASCII (via the `csid=>1` argument to `clob2file`) - it seems reasonable that you can't write non-ASCII characters to an ASCII-only file?

Comment: I Used Oracle Database,when table Data have any ascii char like (character code 128-255) check http://www.ascii-code.com/,that time store procedure shows error like  "ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed.", can I not handled these types of character via store procedure or function.

Comment: I have replace all ascii char <117 from space, and output of ascii char >117 in XML files shoes as a ? char. example of char chr(14844065)

Comment: I assume you mean 127, not 117. The `?` seems fine since the output is 7-bit ASCII due to the `csid` you're specifying - anything over 127 can't be represented, so `?` is used as a marker instead. What generates the ORA-31061 though - you seem to be talking about two issues here now?

Comment: ƒ &#131; &fnof; 
„ &#132; &bdquo;
… &#133; &hellip;
† &#134; &dagger;
‡ &#135; &Dagger;

Comment: Ok, I got that error ORA-31061 when table data have asciichar < 127, and asciichar > 127 shows as a ? in XML files, I an not understand this issue.

Comment: All those characters work fine for me. They are `?` in the file, but that's because the file is ASCII as specified. Characters <= 127 are also fine, and shown as expected. I still don't see how you're triggering the ORA error - your question doesn't show sample data that recreates the problem, and you still haven't said what your character set is. So far I can only get the error if a column has `chr(0)` in it.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to explain my issue here , Can you Connect with me on skype  my ID is hardik.rawal

Comment: I am using encoding=”UTF-8” for generate XML files

Comment: when I ran query SELECT CONVERT('Ä Ê Í Õ Ø A B C D E ', 'US7ASCII', 'WE8ISO8859P1') 
   FROM DUAL; then I got result ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? A B C D E

Comment: US7ASCII only contains ASCII characters, up to 127; not the extended ASCII set. So `Ä Ê Í Õ Ø` do not exist and are represented as `?`, as I said earlier. (Also see the notes about [convert](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm)). Your XML might specify `UTF-8` but your output *file* is ASCII, **because you are setting `csid=>1`** in your [`clob2file` call](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_xslpro.htm#i1007362). See what `select nls_charset_name(1) from dual` says.

Comment: it shows US7ASCII value, how I will update charset  for all ASCII character up to 255

Comment: Use a different `csid`; 0 or left as default for your DB character set, or pick one that's appropriate for your OS (WE8MSWIN1252 on windows, perhaps), or specify a UTF-8 one (e.g. 871). You should read up about globalisation support etc. though, I can't guess what your environment and requirements are. However, that might only cure the `?`, not the ORA error.

Comment: Thanks , Today I learn New in Database, Thanks For Help, for ORA error, when I replace all ASCIICHAR (0-30) like   ♂ : 11  ♀ : 12 
♫ : 14  ☼ : 15  ► : 16  ◄ : 17  ↕ : 18  ‼ : 19  ¶ : 20, (Formatted Letters, less than a  to ASCII values)then , This error has removed.and file generated properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that you're specifying the file should be US7ASCII, which only allows the first 128 ASCII characters, not the extended values from 128-255. You're doing that in this line:

```
dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file( result, 'MYXML', ''||V_TABLE_NAME||'.xml',1);
```

You're passing `1` as [the fourth parameter, `csid`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_xslpro.htm#i1007362). That value represents US7ASCII:

```
SQL> select nls_charset_name(1) from dual;

NLS_CHAR
--------
US7ASCII
```

Your XML is UTF-8, but specifying that with `encoding="UTF-8"` has no bearing on how the file is written. Any unrecognised characters are replaced with `?`. So you might want to use the same setting for the file:

```
SQL> select nls_charset_id('UTF8') from dual;

NLS_CHARSET_ID('UTF8')
----------------------
                   871
```

So:

```
dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file( result, 'MYXML', ''||V_TABLE_NAME||'.xml',871);
```

or to be clearer:

```
dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file( result, 'MYXML', ''||V_TABLE_NAME||'.xml',
  nls_charset_id('UTF8'));
```

But leaving it as the default might be OK - by not specifying `csid` at all, or by explicitly setting it to zero - depending on our database environment.

You mentioned you avoid ORA-31061 error if you "replace all ASCIICHAR (0-30) like ♂ : 11 ♀ : 12 ♫ : 14 ☼ : 15 ► : 16 ◄ : 17 ↕ : 18 ‼ : 19 ¶ : 20". Those symbols aren't what you'd expect from ASCII, so your character set or client or something seems to be interpreting them differently.

I get the error with all the [ASCII control characters](http://www.ascii-code.com/), 0 through to 31, except the printable ones: 9, 10 or 13. But that's what's expected, the other characters in that range [are not valid in XML 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML):

> - U+0009, U+000A, U+000D: these are the only C0 controls accepted in XML 1.0;

The same page shows that more, but still not all, control characters are allowed in XML 1.1, but as far as I'm aware [Oracle only supports 1.0](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23582/adx_ref_standards.htm#ADXDK20021). If you do really have control characters in your data you'll need to strip them (retaining tabs, new lines and carriage returns); the rest would be meaningless in the final XML anyway, and perhaps of limited use in your existing data. I'm not sure if this is real data, or if you'd generated those values as a test.

Comment: if I have not replace all ASCIICHAR (0-30) like ♂ ♀ ♫ ☼ ↕  ‼  ¶ ↓ → ←  and then execute store procedure then got same error shows. "ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed."

Comment: @hardikrawal - most control characters aren't allowed in XML 1.0; I've added that to my answer.